# node js задать базовый корневой путь?

Tags: node.js

Можно ли задать чтобы корневой путь начинался с указанного каталога?

То есть передаю путь в модуле fs в функции чтения `'/data/file.txt',`
но этот корневой будет начинаться с `'/home/user/'`
то есть файл будет считываться с '`/home/user/data/file.txt'`.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Comment: Эту команду можно вызвать из модуля fs nodejs?
Если программа запущена обычным образом, то как выполнить для неё chroot?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/posix#posixchrootpath